# How do I list iTunes apps by the account that purchased it?

Tags: itunes, applications, accounts, sort

I've got more than one person downloading apps to my iTunes, and so I'd like to list all apps purchased by one account (meaning the same email address). How can I separate apps like this? I can't seem to find any columns that I can add to the Apps tab to sort apps in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to sort them in mass, you could one-by-one right click on each app, select 'Get Info' and then a window will pop up with app info.

Under the summary tab you will see (middle right hand side of the window) 'Purchased By' and 'Account Name'.

Sorry but that's currently the only way. Unless your on a Mac and can code a shell script.

Comment: Frustrated with there being no way (which was correct at the time of posting), I came up with the shell script below to dump the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can try in Terminal.

```
$ for f in ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/*.ipa ; \
  do (echo "$f" ; unzip -p "$f" "iTunesMetadata.plist" | \
  plutil -p - | egrep -i "\"(itemName|artistName|AppleID)\"" ) | \
  perl -e 'while (<>) { if (m!^/!) { chop; $fqn=$_; } if (m/"(.+)" => (".+")/) { $e{lc($1)}=$2; } } print "\"${fqn}\",$e{\"itemname\"},$e{\"artistname\"},$e{\"appleid\"}\n";'; \
done
```

[Here is a blogpost](http://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2012/11/18/list-itunes-apps-by-purchaser/) where this action is explained.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work `unrecognized option: -p`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: According to the OS X man page on unzip, the -p option extracts files to a pipe (stdout). Use an equivalent option, though note this script was intended for OS X.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise: I'm running this on OS X and the `unzip -p` part seems to work, but it chokes saying `unrecognized option: -p plutil: [command_option] [other_options] file... The file '-' means stdin`, followed by the output of `plutil --help`. I haven't been able to figure out either what `-p` is supposed to do for `plutil`. Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The option, which is new to Mountain Lion, dumps out the object in a JSON-like format, fit for human consumption (and thus searchable by a script). I'm surprised Apple's online man page isn't reflecting it, it's used all over the web. (e.g., Google for "plutil -p" and examples come up)   I'll see if I can dig up a resource with it.

Comment: ah bummer, that explains the error, as I'm running 10.7 here and I cannot upgrade for the time being. There wouldn't be a way without the `-p` that you know of?